# How to solve this error in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I'm getting an error when using the following code

```
var v1 = from P in db1.QuranWordsNews where P.Aye == perId select P;
var vv = v1.LastOrDefault(); // The error occurs here
```

The message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'TashihQuran.QuranWordsNew
>   LastOrDefaultQuranWordsNew'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error, method not supported by LINQ to Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170141/error-method-not-supported-by-linq-to-entities)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ To Entities does not recognize the method Last. Really?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293639/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-last-really)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I guess you're still working in `IQueriable`. Try instead

```
var vv = v1.ToList().LastOrDefault();
```

or, more elegant

```
var vv = v1.AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 45):

Maybe the better answer is here :

```
var vv = v1.OrderByDescending(rec => rec.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

**Fetch all records from database to use just the last record is not good.**

Comment: Agree with your statement, but in OP's case, doesn't v1 already contain "all records" from database?