# Linq2Sql nested tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a problem with my LINQ2SQL query. I'm trying get only that `TabA` rows where associated `TabC` `Name` column contains e.g lorem. Any ideas ?

I try

```
(from x in db.TabA
 x.TabB.FirstOrDefault(y => y.TabC.name == "lorem") != null
 x).ToList();
```

but I get the `method is not supported error`.

[image]

Comment: What does Default mean for a Table?

Comment: Try to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170141/error-method-not-supported-by-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

```
(from x in db.TabA
 where x.TabB.Count(a => a.TabC.name == "lorem") > 0
 select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this 
Its working like 'like' query in sql.

```
(from x in db.TabA
 where x.TabB.Count(a => a.TabC.name.contains("lorem")) > 0
 select x).ToList();
```